# Logoff User when browser tab page is closed, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In one of the ASP.NET MVC apps we would like to logoff the user automatically if he closes the browser tab in which the app is opened.

We are using the following code when he authenticates.

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false)

As of now, if we closes the browser window and relaunch it, users are asked to authenticate again. But we want to ask users to authenticate again if they close the tab and try to access any of the website urls.

Comment: I question the feature. What if the user has your site open in two tabs, and closes one?

Comment: There's no any reliable way of doing this and I don't see any reason for implementing such a *feature*.

Comment: I can understand the need for this if you are trying to account for concurrent users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We decided to use cookie less authentication so that the authentication token is part of the url. When the tab is closed and they open the website again, they will be asked to authenticate again :)

Comment: This means that authentication tokens are going to be saved in a lot more places then you expect - many corporate firewalls and other filters log the url. Even your own website logs will show them (meaning that you just gave any network admin or data center employee with basic file access the ability to impersonate users by copying the url from the standard IIS/Apache log file)

Comment: I have redirect it to LogOff in body tag, unload event, Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60840992/747897

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this myself, but I think the following approach should work:

On the client side, you can use the OnUnload event of your document to launch a javascript function that would call your server-side signout method via ajax.

On the server side, you should have the action method call FormsAuthentication.SignOut() and Session.Abandon();

Comment: Be careful with this, though, as the onunload fires when navigating away from the page as well. And as far as I know, there isn't any way to check if the user is navigating or closing...

Comment: unload is fired before moving to every page of the website. But I want to handle tab close.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you might not be writing an AJAX website. I am loading all new content via AJAX calls (using a custom-made jquery plugin), so I only get an unloadevent when the tab or window is closed.

Answer (score 3):

A browser clears all Session scoped objects only when it is completely closed, and not when an individual tab is closed.

One way could be to use a very low Session timeout and have a server-side script poll every few seconds to hit an object on the page. This will extend Session time again. So if a tab is closed, the script can't find the object thereby allowing the Session to timeout. One problem here is if your app is on a pretty high load, your app could DoS itself!

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no way we can LogOff the user when the user closes the browser tab. The only way for this is to check if the the user is authenticated when we call the LogOn method in the Controller.

This code is an example of how I do it in ASP.Net MVC 3.

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                return RedirectToAction("Index","ProductManager");  
            }
           return View();          
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use session variables to automatically log off anybody trying to return to the secured destination page. Create a single session variable (integer or boolean) and in the onclick event of your login button reset it to a known state after acknowledging that the user has a valid credential then set or increment that session variable in the page_load event of the page your trying to secure. Test these values and signout the user if he is trying to return to the page or do nothing if otherwise. The code may look similar to this.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
         if (IsAuthenticated == true)
         Session["IsUserLoggedIn"] = (int)0;
 }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
                {
                        if (Session["IsUserLoggedIn"] != null)
                        {
                                int IsUserLoggedIn = (int)Session["IsUserLoggedIn"];
                                if (IsUserLoggedIn <= 0)
                                {
                                        Session["IsUserLoggedIn"] = (int)IsUserLoggedIn + 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        Session["IsUserLoggedIn"] = (int)0;
                                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                                }
                        }
                }
                else { Session["IsUserLoggedIn"] = (int)0; } 
        }
```

Comment: This approach has a serious bug. After login if I refresh the home page where in the above Page_Load has been implemented, it do logout me.